# Running cypress tests in ADO pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress

When running cypress tests in pipeline (Azure devops), I am getting this error:

[image]

Does someone know the solution for this?
When running tests locally or opening link, everything is ok and everything is working as expected.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your pipeline have access to your website? Is the website local or deployed? The error message is pretty clear on what is happening - Cypress can't find the website defined in your Cypress config.

Comment: Yes, it has. It is deployed website. When I run cypress test on my computer in VS code, everything is working as it should.

Comment: I found something that I should start and boot the server, when using tests in CI-CD, but I am not sure how to do it....